# Показ открытого файла в дереве проекта PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Я хочу, чтобы при открытии, переходе между файлами в проекте, в дереве проекта отображалось это переключение. Т.е когда я нахожу в test.js, я хочу, чтобы в дереве проекта также указывалось на файл test.js. Как это можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте включить опцию **Always Select Opened File** в настройках проектного дерева:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В предыдущих версиях эта опция называлась **Auto-scroll from Source** - если Вы используете старую версию, попробуйте выбрать ее.

Когда она выключена (как у Вас), в тулбаре Project tool window доступна кнопка **Select Opened File**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Супер, помогло. Недавно на вебшторм, и с выключенной этой настройкой постоянно дезориентировался